# The pop-up contact form on my website is slightly not centered when viewed on mobile phones

Tags: php, wordpress, center, gravity-forms-plugin

My website is www.myfixerhouse.com 
If you click on any one of the links on the webpage a contact form pops up. However, when the form is viewed on a mobile phone or on a smaller screen, something is preventing it from being centered. [Contact form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLNIc.png)

The website is made with Wordpress and the contact form is made with the plugin Gravity Forms. I would like to know how I can make the contact form to be centered on the mobile phone.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to edit the CSS file. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Check out my answer and let me know if you have any questions. Should fix the problem for you!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `.modal-dialog` has a set margin of 10px

[image]

in Chrome if you right click on your contact form (like the input boxes) and go to Inspect then hover you mouse up to the parent `<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">` you'll see that Chrome shows us there is a margin around this div that your contact form is in. this pushes your contact form across.

if you play with the Window Width you'll see how when the screen is more than 450px there is a tiny gap on the right that appears.

if we remove the margin from the CSS Class we havew the contact form flesh against the edge of the window.

[image]

but if you want to have that gap i would suggest changing `margin` to `padding`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That actually helps!

Answer (score -1):

I've visited your site and played around with the styling using the Chrome developer console. I found that the "modal-dialog" div encapsulating the form has a 10px margin on the left and right sides which cause the form to be pushed 10px to the right on smaller screens.

Simply set `margin: 0px` on the `modal-dialog` element and you should be good to go! [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr00n.jpg) what it should look like when you're done.

You may need to install a plugin such as this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/ in order to style the plugin since you don't have direct access. Once you've done so, just add

```css
.modal-dialog {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

to your CSS. If it doesn't listen to your changes, add the `!important` flag to the property.